# What is the best place for the viewport tag

Tags: html

I'm wondering what is the best place to put the viewport tag.

after `<title>` tag, before CSS links, before/after html5shiv (old browsers) and if possible why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about `<meta name="viewport">` (because there's no such thing as `<viewport>`), you can put it anywhere you like, as long as you keep it somewhere within the `<head>` tag for it to be valid HTML.

It doesn't matter whether it comes before or after the `<title>` tag, `<link>` tags, or even the HTML5 shiv, because `<meta>` tags are widely supported and don't require the HTML5 shiv as they already exist in older specifications (and as mentioned, it's `<meta name="viewport">`, not `<viewport>`).

Comment: Of course, I meant `<meta name="viewport">`. Thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) (which is a good source for this sort of thing) puts it here:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/style.less">
    <script src="js/libs/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script>window.html5 || document.write('<script src="js/libs/html5.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

But I don't think it matters so long as its in the `head`.